# web.xml versus programmatic approach

Tags: java, servlets, configuration, jetty, web.xml

Adding more and more **configurations** to my **servlet container** (**Embedded Jetty** in my case) I am starting to wonder whether I should put everything into a **web.xml** or keep the configuration **programmatic** in the Java code.

Are there reasons to choose web.xml over programmatic approach and vice versa? Are there **security reasons** or is this only cosmetic?

To me it seems web.xml is better since you dedicate a DSL to do the job instead of pressing everything into the code. On the other side I can look up configuration quickly when I am in the code.

Comment: which kind of configuration are you talking about?

Comment: Actually every configuration which can be done, at the moment I am only configuring servlet mapping and constraints, like JAAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to configure and your convenience.

Servlet 3.0 allows you define the metadata in three different ways:

**web.xml**, Usually configuration which will change while being deployed on different environments  should be configured here. These properties are such as Database properties, properties file, Admin user properties, etc.

The advantage of defining in web.xml, all the configuration exists at central place and it is easy for documentation etc.Being defined only at one place, it is difficult for maintainence during distributed development. Yes, Again Servlet 3.0 allows web-fragments.xml for which you should be defining library which can again have single descriptor per library.

**Annotations**, Anything which can be defined during development but can be also overridden during deployment is defined as annotations.

The advantage is No need to configure in deployment descriptor unless it has to be overridden. The annotations can give the default values.
The disadvantage is that the Container has to process all classes for annotations. I don't see this as big disadvantage.

**Programatically**, Anything which you know that is not going to change can be configured programatically The advantage is that the developer is sure that the configuration is not going be altered anytime by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

To apply new settings using web.config you need only change config file and restart application.  In case of keeping configuration in code you will need to rebuild project.

Comment: I have thought of that, too. But why then mind the programmatic approach?

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, you can use web.xml for some config that rarely change like (if you use Jersey):

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.vogella.jersey.first</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

(I copy these codes from http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)

Programmatic config will be good in case if config will regularly change and update (you can check  Netflix Archaius)

For example: service timed-out, thread-pool size, or metrics tracking, etc...